# validating my mvc error handling

Tags: c#, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-5, global-asax

I have this in place in global.asax, and I was hoping some folks could tell me if I'm making any glaring mistakes. This my first MVC application.

```
        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
            {
                throw Server.GetLastError();
            }

            Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
            Response.Clear();

            //here I email (exception.ToString()) to a helpdesk system.

            Server.ClearError();

            Response.Redirect("/Error/");

        }
```

Basically I wanted something that would:

a) Let me get the raw thrown exception when in debug.

b) In production, send the exception to a logging service / helpdesk app.

c) In production, hide the exception from the user and present a simple error page.

So far it seems to work just fine but was just curious if there's anything wrong with my approach.

Comment: also try posting this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Please refer custome error configuration in web config